# R missing variable that is conditional on the others that are present

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R and I'm trying to fill out two missing values at the same time. I had used the `pad` function from `library(padr)` to fill out the data frame with missing date values. Now I have two additional fields that are `NA`.

I know what these values should be but I don't understand an easy way to code them into the dataframe and the dataframe is too long to do it manually.

The missing field for the sales column should be `0`. The harder part here is the `store` column. There are three options for stores: `store1`, `store2`, `store3`. And each value in the `Date` will be listed three times. I don't know which store is missing for each day. In the example I'm including here, `store2` is missing but later in the data frame it might be `store1` or `store3`. Is there a way to fill out the missing store by knowing the other two stores that are missing?

Here is a screenshot of my dataframe.

[image]

And here is a section of it so it's reproducible.

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18628, 18628, 18628, 18629, 
18629, 18629, 18630, 18630, 18630, 18631, 18631, 18631), class = "Date"), 
    store = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("store1", "store2", "store3"), class = "factor"), 
    sales = c(153461, 2332, 1734, 176912, 53063, 17484, 243581, 
    NA, 412, 1739263, 427311, 9772)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), groups = structure(list(
    store = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, NA), .Label = c("store1", 
    "store2", "store3"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L), c(2L, 5L, 11L, 12L), c(3L, 6L, 9L
        ), 8L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want a balanced pannel (for each date, three rows, one per store). I would go as follows:

Create a balanced dataset with dates and stores.

```
stores<-c('store1','store2','store3')
dates<-seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'),as.Date('2001-07-22'),by='day')
data<-data.frame(expand.grid(stores,dates))
```

And now, left join your dataset. It will leave NA the sales column if it is not there, but you can fill it with a 0 easily.

```
names(data)[1] <- "store" 
names(data)[2] <- "date" 

df2 <- left_join(data, df)

df2$sales[is.na(df2$sales)] <- 0
```

Comment: Great thank you for the good suggestion with expand.grid. I added additional code and cleaned up very small errors just to make sure it runs.